# Object creation & release is not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I Created ViewController.Here two buttons are creating & releasing the NSObject.

```
// This Button for creating & assign the values to the NSObject.
- (IBAction)CreateObjectBtn:(id)sender 
{
    [cpFileObject methodForRetain];  
    // Here the tempFilePath  = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Innum_Enna_Thozha-VmusiQ.Com" ofType:@"mp3"];
    cpFileObject.fileData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:tempFilePath];
    cpFileObject.filePath = tempFilePath;  
}

// This Button for **release** the NSObject from memory Pool.
- (IBAction)releaseObjectBtn:(id)sender 
{
    [cpFileObject methodForRelease];    
}
```

**The NSObject Name - CPFile.**

```
// This Instance Method for **Increase** the allocation of NSObject.
-(void)methodForRetain
{
    if (!fileData) 
    {
        [fileData retain];
    }       
}

// This Instance Method for **Decrease** the allocation of NSObject.
- (void)methodForRelease
{
    [fileData release];
    NSLog(@"%lu Object released ",(unsigned long)self.retainCount);       
}
```

The Problem is occurring in Creating & Releasing is working only two or three times. After if I click the `CreateObjectBtn`. The Error is showing like this.

[image: Error code in CPFile Object]

Comment: Can you insert your code?

Comment: Ya. can I paste here? @bsarr007..

Comment: Already I pasted my code . please verify and let me.

Comment: you are releasing autorelease object, do this cpFileObject.fileData =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:tempFilePath];

Comment: Still am facing same error@Rajneesh071

Comment: `methodForRetain` will only retain a nil pointer.  And even if it retained something, you immediately overwrite that pointer.

Comment: You have enough trouble just understanding what a pointer is.  Use ARC so you don't need to do retain/release.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because programmer does not understand pointers.

Comment: Note that your `methodForRetain` will only retain an object if the pointer to it is nil.

Answer (score 0):

If you see your Queue from **Viewcontroller2** in

`[Viewcontroller2 playBtn:]`

you are trying to setFileData(setting property).

[image]

Just try to log your value what you are setting and FileData.

Comment: Am tried NSData is printing..but second time when i press playBtn: bad access is arising.

Comment: what are you setting in to that property?

Comment: We are setting song data into that property @rajesh

Comment: you tried logging tht data? my questin is is you data proper? in one of my project i faced such issue. i strugged a lot to find the issue the problem is one array was holding the reference of itself..

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!fileData) 
{
     [fileData retain];
}
```

There is nothing to retain.

You should create an object first. Your `[fileData retain]` should be replaced by:

```
if (!fileData) 
{
     fileData =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:tempFilePath];
}
```

Comment: If I do like this also same problem was occurred.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    - (IBAction)CreateObjectBtn:(id)sender 
    {
        cpFileObject.fileData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:tempFilePath];
        cpFileObject.filePath = tempFilePath; 
        [cpFileObject methodForRetain];  //move it down
    }

    -(void)methodForRetain
    {
        [fileData retain]; //it doesn't matter if fileData is nil; 
    }
```